# create thumbnail for blob with php

Tags: php, image, blob

It is very easy to create a thumbnail as a file but I can't figure out how to use the PHP image functions to create an image and store the data inside a variable witch I can use to store the data inside a database table.

I am new to the image functions and I do not understand their working. Are they directory orientated? So I have to create something like a tmp map for the thumbnail maker and then just use file_get_content and then remove the image.

Or can I some how store the data of the image during the process. I have no idea!

This is how I create thumbnails if I need to save them as a file:

```
//found at stackoverflow
function tumbmaker($updir, $img,$MaxWe=100,$MaxHe=150){
    $arr_image_details = getimagesize($img); 
    $width = $arr_image_details[0];
    $height = $arr_image_details[1];

    $percent = 100;
    if($width > $MaxWe) $percent = floor(($MaxWe * 100) / $width);

    if(floor(($height * $percent)/100)>$MaxHe)  
    $percent = (($MaxHe * 100) / $height);

    if($width > $height) {
        $newWidth=$MaxWe;
        $newHeight=round(($height*$percent)/100);
    }else{
        $newWidth=round(($width*$percent)/100);
        $newHeight=$MaxHe;
    }

    if ($arr_image_details[2] == 1) {
        $imgt = "ImageGIF";
        $imgcreatefrom = "ImageCreateFromGIF";
    }
    if ($arr_image_details[2] == 2) {
        $imgt = "ImageJPEG";
        $imgcreatefrom = "ImageCreateFromJPEG";
    }
    if ($arr_image_details[2] == 3) {
        $imgt = "ImagePNG";
        $imgcreatefrom = "ImageCreateFromPNG";
    }


    if ($imgt) {
        $old_image = $imgcreatefrom($img);
        $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
        imagecopyresized($new_image, $old_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);

       $imgt($new_image, $updir."_t.jpg");
        return;    
    }
}
```

I did it with this code:

```
function tumbmaker($img_source,$MaxWe=100,$MaxHe=150){
        $arr_image_details = getimagesize($img_source); 
        $width = $arr_image_details[0];
        $height = $arr_image_details[1];

        $percent = 100;
        if($width > $MaxWe) $percent = floor(($MaxWe * 100) / $width);

        if(floor(($height * $percent)/100)>$MaxHe)  
        $percent = (($MaxHe * 100) / $height);

        if($width > $height) {
            $newWidth=$MaxWe;
            $newHeight=round(($height*$percent)/100);
        }else{
            $newWidth=round(($width*$percent)/100);
            $newHeight=$MaxHe;
        }

        if ($arr_image_details[2] == 1) {
            $imgt = "ImageGIF";
            $imgcreatefrom = "ImageCreateFromGIF";
        }
        if ($arr_image_details[2] == 2) {
            $imgt = "ImageJPEG";
            $imgcreatefrom = "ImageCreateFromJPEG";
        }
        if ($arr_image_details[2] == 3) {
            $imgt = "ImagePNG";
            $imgcreatefrom = "ImageCreateFromPNG";
        }


        if ($imgt) {
            $old_image = $imgcreatefrom($img_source);
            $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
            imagecopyresized($new_image, $old_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);
            $imgt($new_image, $updir."_t.jpg");
            ob_start();
            $imgt($new_image);
            $imgData = ob_get_clean();
            return $imgData;
        }
}
```

Read the answer for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you supply no file name to the image creation functions they will simply write the image data into PHP's output buffer.

That means you can intercept the image data like this:

```
ob_start();
$imgt($new_image);
$imgData = ob_get_clean();
```

Have a look at the [PHP GD Manual](http://php.net/gd).